# Why epoll_event only have 32bit pointer when getted from epoll_wait

Tags: c++, linux, epoll

I have func1 that add event:
`c++`

```
func1(args...) {
    //....do something.....
    struct epoll_event ev;
    ev.events = events;
    ev.data.ptr = (void*)(*s); // s is own data.
    printf("add io event address is %p seted is %p\n", *s, ev.data.ptr);

    return epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &ev);
}
```

but when i use epoll_wait int func2, struct epoll_event only get half pointer address:

```
func2(args...) {
    // ....do someting....
    int cnt = epoll_wait(event->epollfd, event->events, MAX_EVENT_EACH_LOOP, usec);
    if (cnt > 0) {
        event->status = SD_EVENT_INITIAL;
        printf("epoll wait get %p %p\n", static_cast<sd_event_source *>(event- 
        >events[0].data.ptr), (void *)event->events[0].data.u32);
        event->event_cnt = cnt;
    }
/// do someting
return cnt;
```

stdout info:

```
add io event address is 0x564fb2801470 seted is 0x564fb2801470
epoll wait get 0xb2801470 0xb2801470
```

Comment: In a 64bit build, you need to use `data.u64` instead of `data.u32`. But `data.ptr` should not be getting truncated though, that is odd.

Comment: @LouisGo if it were, `%p` would be printing 32bit addresses, but it is clearly printing 64bit addresses instead.

Comment: `(void*)(*s)` looks fishy, are you sure with that? Why are you using C-style casts at all when you know about C++ casts?

Answer (score 0):

cross compile issues, i link wrong arch version *.so.(arm64 instead of arm)